# getting error - Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

im getting error - "Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."

code

```
    string name = txtName.Text.Trim();
    string email = txtemail.Text.Trim();
    string phone = txtPhoneNum.Text.Trim();
    string companyname = txtcmpnm.Text.Trim();
    string subject = txtsubject.Text.Trim();
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    System.IO.StreamReader r = null;
    r = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/ContactMail.txt"));
    string body = r.ReadToEnd();

    body = body.Replace("<%Name%>", name);
    body = body.Replace("<%email%>", email);
    body = body.Replace("<%phonenum%>", txtPhoneNum.Text.Trim());
    body = body.Replace("<%message%>", txtmsg.Text.Trim());


    try
    {


    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(email, "xyz@gmail.com"))
    {
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.Body = body;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("krishna@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web.Cofig:-

Check your web.config and add this tag code...

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: in which tag i need to write, im using .net 3.5 framework

Comment: in the localhost mail sending properly , but in the godaddy server its showing error - failure sending mail.

Comment: [OR] Try this code---- Host:   relay-hosting.secureserver.net,
 Port:   25 ,
 Enable SSL: not checked

Comment: i changed host and port and ssl, now its working fine